# Prove that $\det(AB - BA) = \frac{1}{3}\left(\mathrm{Trace}(AB - BA)^3\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I want a correct and feasible answer to this question. 
So does anyone have any creative ideas to prove this equation?

> $A$ and $B$ are $3\times3$ matrices.
>   $\det(AB - BA) = \dfrac{1}{3}\operatorname{Trace}\left((AB - BA)^3\right)$

Answer:
We can write and compute both sides to prove it but this is not a good solution!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This follows easily from Cayley-Hamilton theorem. Since $M=AB-BA$ has zero trace, by Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $M^3=cM+dI_3$ where $c$ is some scalar and $d=\det(M)$. Therefore $\operatorname{tr}(M^3)=3d$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 8):

Choose a basis which puts $AB-BA$ in Jordan normal form (both $\det$ and $\text{Tr}$ are invariant under basis change, so this is allowed).  Then since a commutator is traceless, the diagonal must have the form $(a,b,-a-b)$.  Then $\det(AB-BA)=-ab(a+b)$, and $$\frac{1}{3}\text{Tr}(AB-BA)^3=\frac{1}{3}(a^3+b^3-(a+b)^3) = -ab(a+b)$$ as desired.

Answer (score 8):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Properties) gives the following identity for the determinant of a $k\times k$ matrix:
$$\det A=
\frac{1}{k!}  
\det\begin{pmatrix}  \operatorname{tr}A  &   k-1 &0&\cdots & \\
\operatorname{tr}A^2  &\operatorname{tr}A&  k-2 &\cdots & \\
 \vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & \vdots    \\
\operatorname{tr}A^{k-1} &\operatorname{tr}A^{k-2}& & \cdots & 1    \\ 
\operatorname{tr}A^k  &\operatorname{tr}A^{k-1}& & \cdots & \operatorname{tr}A
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
In particular when $k=3$, and using $AB-BA$ in place of $A$, we have that
$$
\det (AB-BA)=\frac{1}{3!}\det\begin{pmatrix} 0 &   2 &0 \\
\operatorname{tr}(AB-BA)^2  &0&  1 \\
\operatorname{tr}(AB-BA)^{3} &\operatorname{tr}(AB-BA)^{2}& 0   \\ 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Expanding the determinant along the top row yields your formula.

Comment: There's a sign error. Even the $k=1$ case gives it away: it should be $(-1)^{k-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. Actually I had it right originally, then right before posting managed to confuse myself and put in the $(-1)^k$. And in the end it should just be $1$, not $(-1)^{k-1}$. Signs can be so annoying sometimes...

Answer (score 8):

Another proof.  It is known that for an arbitrary $3 \times 3$ matrix $M$, [we have](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicPolynomial.html) 
$$
\det(M) = \frac 16\left[ \operatorname{tr}^3(M) + 2 \operatorname{tr}(M^3)
-3\operatorname{tr}(M)\operatorname{tr}(M^2)\right]
$$
Setting $M = AB - BA$, we note that $\operatorname{tr}(M) = 0$ so that the above simplifies to 
$$
\det(M) = \frac 13 \operatorname{tr}(M^3)
$$
which is the formula that we wanted.

Comment: Note that - while it may not be apparent at a glance - this answer uses the same identity as mine, except my answers expresses the mysterious cubic polynomial in this answer as the determinant of a memorable $3\times 3$ matrix.